# VB.NET Settings (Import)

Tags: vb.net

I want it to do the following: When they click the import button, open multiple files (done) then save them as a settings. Then on form load, open those files so I do not have to re-import them!

I have tried this

```
For Each wl As String In File.ReadAllLines("settings.txt")
        OpenFileDialog1.FileName = (wl)
    Next
```

on form load and settings.txt included 2 file names and locations. It is only opening the 2nd file NOT the first. How can I make it open ALL files in that settings file? I also tied ReadLines

Comment: You... um... can't do it even close to that way. Where's your method that opens a file? Call that in the loop.

Comment: Lol it is. OpenFileDialog1.FileName = (wl)
Now I found that the problem is that anything after the first file on the list of imported files is not working. Only the first file works

Comment: No, that's not your method that opens a file. That sets the file name of your *file dialog*. What code actually reads the file?

Comment: Ignore that for now,  OpenFileDialog1.FileName = (wl) Now I found that the problem is that anything after the first file on the list of imported files is not working. Only the first file works.. and it is there, File.ReadAllLines reads the settings file.

Comment: No, it's not "ignore that for now". Setting `OpenFileDialog1.FileName` *does not load your file*, which is what you're trying to do, correct? It will be overwritten on each iteration of the loop, and there's your other problem. Or are you trying to do something else entirely?

Comment: What I am trying to do is figure out why it is only reading the contents of the first file and not anything after. The code that reads the file is 


`Dim firstWord = (From word In IO.File.ReadLines(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
             Where String.Equals(SHA1(word), hash.Text)).FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: And how does that code get called? Can you show the whole body of the method that contains that line, please?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/6a6FDjEF
Sorry, the code was to long to put here

Comment: It doesn't appear to deal with multiple files in the first place. So what do you want to do when multiple files are selected? Just stitch them together?

Comment: Basically I want the program to read the contents of both and compare them to a string that is entered but I guess stitching them together would work as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easiest to just abstract your hash-cracker method out:

```
Function hashType(ByVal filename As String) As Boolean
    If algo.Text = "MD5" Then
        Dim firstWord = (From word In IO.File.ReadLines(filename)
         Where String.Equals(MD5(word), hash.Text)).FirstOrDefault()
        If firstWord IsNot Nothing Then
            Label2.Text = firstWord
            Return True
        Else
            Label2.Text = "Hash Could Not Be Cracked"
        End If
    ElseIf algo.Text = "SHA1" Then
        Dim firstWord = (From word In IO.File.ReadLines(filename)
         Where String.Equals(SHA1(word), hash.Text)).FirstOrDefault()
        If firstWord IsNot Nothing Then
            Label2.Text = firstWord
            Return True
        Else
            Label2.Text = "Hash Could Not Be Cracked"
        End If
    End If

    Return False
End Function

Private Sub Thief3Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Thief3Button1.Click
    OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Dictionaries (*.dic)|*.dic"
    OpenFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1
    OpenFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = True
    OpenFileDialog1.Multiselect = True
    OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
End Sub

Private Sub Thief3TopButton1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Thief3TopButton1.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub Thief3Button3_Click_2(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Thief3Button2.Click
    hashType(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For Each wl As String In File.ReadLines("settings.txt")
        If hashType(wl) Then Exit For
    Next
End Sub
```

Voilà. I think you'll probably want to do this somewhere other than in the `Load` event, though - there won't be anything in `hash.Text` when the form is first created.

Comment: That isn't going to work lol. I'm trying to make a passwords pro program thing. It's all ready except the wordlist error

Comment: *"That isn't going to work lol."* It would be really helpful if you could give a reason why it isn't going to work. And not "lol" :)

Comment: Because I am importing a wordlist to test the entered hash against the hash of each word in the imported wordlist!

Comment: Once again, the actual error would be helpful. (In fact, it would have been nice in the first comment...)

Comment: Could not find file 'C:\Users\Joe\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\HashCracker\HashCracker\bin\Debug\OpenFileDialog1'.

Comment: I guess now I just need a script to combine the multiple imported files

Comment: So... didja put `OpenFileDialog1` as one of the lines in `settings.txt`? It's not supposed to be there.

Comment: No I didn't put it in settings

Comment: So... when does the error occur? When you click on the button? Without selecting a file? Are you sure you copied the code properly?

Comment: ... then that would be because you haven't selected a file. Read the note at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: We are kinda spamming lol Do you have a skype or MSN or Yahoo?

Comment: Don't worry about it, no spamming. Anyway, if you are planning to make use of this feature as given, note that it does not involve clicking "Run" in any way. It runs when the form loads. If you don't want that, maybe heed my warning that it shouldn't be in the `Form.Load` handler.

Comment: I think it would be easier for you to see how the program works, another reason I was asking about skype or something